# C++ Preprocessor semicolon

Tags: c++

I want to write code like this `MAKE var=NUMBER: 21`, which can be translated to
 `auto var=21;`.

I have defined the following macros: `#define MAKE auto` and
`#define NUMBER (1==0)?` , but they did not work well.

To put it simple, I would like to add the semicolon at the end of the definition automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you inventing your own syntax?

Comment: Don't fight the language, embrace it and embrace its flaws. Otherwise you are gonna make everything even worse.

Comment: @Ivan Stephen Bourne used macros to make C look like Algol when he was writing the Bourne Shell. :)

Comment: @Barmar This is probably the reason why bash is so bad.

Comment: @Ivan I'm pretty sure bash is a from-scratch rewrite, it doesn't use any of Bourne's coding style.

Comment: @Barmar I wasn't talking about the source code.

Comment: @Ivan Then what were you talking about? What is it about `bash`, as opposed to other shells that inherit their syntax from Bourne shell, that's so bad? Or are you talking about all Bourne-like shells, because their syntax is very Algol-like?

Comment: @Barmar bash is the reason why Bourne-like language is now so common.

Comment: @Ivan Hardly. Bourne shell was already the de facto standard shell long before `bash`, that's why it copied it. The only alternative was `csh`, which was never a good scripting language.

Answer (score 2):

It is not achievable with C++ macro syntax. You have only macro before 21 and not after. Though you can achieve that if you change your syntax slightly:

```
MAKE var=NUMBER(21)
```

instead of

```
MAKE var=NUMBER: 21
```

and define NUMBER as:

```
#define NUMBER(x) (x);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers.Actually i am trying to make a version of LOGO which is like that and thats the reason for this specific syntax